Initializing floating point numbers from string variables in expl3
I am having problems by initialization of floats from strings. I need to do it as I parse some tokens, which then are e.g. of the form "1.0" or "31". More precisely I have expressions such as "35-39!0.3" which I parse and put to the strings \l_wphase_from_str, \l_wphase_to_str \l_wphase_force_str
Then I wish to transform those strings to floats
\fp_new:N \l_wphase_from_fp
\fp_new:N \l_wphase_len_fp
\fp_new:N \l_wphase_force_fp
\fp_new:N \l_wphase_effort_fp    
\fp_set:Nn \l_wphase_from_fp {\l_wphase_from_str}
\fp_set:Nn \l_wphase_len_fp {\l_wphase_to_str - \l_wphase_from_str}
\fp_gset:Nn \l_wphase_force_fp {\l_wphase_force_str}
\fp_gset:Nn \l_wphase_effort_fp {\l_wphase_force_fp * \l_wphase_len_fp}

Sometimes it works without problems.
Sometimes I have errors like
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.104 }
       
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

I do not know how to do it right.

Welcome to TeX.SE.  Can you give some code that you think should work, but produces that error?  And what is the ! operator?  Is that factorial?  (Unrelated, but gset should act on a \g_wphase, not a \l_wphase.)

Please, add a complete example that produces the error. Those code snippets aren’t enough.

your error clearly shows you are using a command defined to use \protect so that is code unrelated to the code that you have shown which is all expl3 code which never uses \protect. Please edit your post so that the example matches the question.

For recovering the value of a ⟨str var⟩ you need to use \str_use:N or \str_use:c.
Probably s.th. like the following does the trick:
\fp_new:N \l_wphase_from_fp
\fp_new:N \l_wphase_len_fp
\fp_new:N \l_wphase_force_fp
\fp_new:N \l_wphase_effort_fp    
\fp_set:Nn \l_wphase_from_fp {\str_use:N \l_wphase_from_str}
\fp_set:Nn \l_wphase_len_fp {(\str_use:N\l_wphase_to_str) - (\str_use:N\l_wphase_from_str)}
\fp_set:Nn \l_wphase_force_fp {\str_use:N\l_wphase_force_str}
\fp_set:Nn \l_wphase_effort_fp {(\l_wphase_force_fp) * (\l_wphase_len_fp)}

Whether this solves the problem cannot be told for sure as long as it is unknown what tokens form the values of expl3-variables \l_wphase_from_str⁠/​\l_wphase_to_str⁠/​\l_wphase_force_str and thus it cannot be predicted whether some of those tokens trigger errors in the course of evaluating a ⟨floating point expression⟩.
